# Python : how to extract a value from a database (from yfinance)

Tags: python, dataframe, finance, yahoo-finance

I am trying to learn how to use Python properly for finance so I tried to do a code to extract a currency rate from yahoofinance. Currently I get what I want but I would like to extract just a value from the data (the 'Close' price).

My code :

```
import yfinance  as yf
#import panda as pd
from datetime import date

ccy_ticker ='GBPUSD=X'
dateofday = date.today()
today = dateofday.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
df = yf.download(ccy_ticker,start=today,end=today)
print(type(df))
```

The output is a dataframe with several column (Open, High, etc.) and I want to get the Close value as floating number.

Thanks for your help .
Regards.

Comment: After extracting, you can simply select the value of the close price by selecting the column: `df.Close`. If you want it separately, just as float, you can use `float(df.Close)`

Comment: thanks for your answer , when I do this  I obtain :
Date
2020-11-09    2.318061
Name: Close, dtype: float64
Why the field Date (and the date) is still there ?

Comment: Because it comes out as a series. If you had more than one exchange rate, it would show each rate for each date. Because you are extracting only today's exchange rate, you can easily turn it into a float by doing `float(df.Close)`

Comment: thank you very much I get it , sorry if my question was stupid for you , starting to play with dataframe so I am not yet comfortable haha.